# Does memcpy free the original memory?

Tags: c

When memcpy() is used, does this free the original memory?
It is for an assessment so I can't share the orignal code. The code works but valgrind shows a memory leak where the original array was declared.

For example:

```
//first array
animal** dogs= malloc(sizeof(animal*) * 5);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    dogs[i] = malloc(sizeof(animal));
    dogs[i]->name = "doggo";
}

//second array
animal** cats; = malloc(sizeof(animal*) * 3);
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    cats[i] = malloc(sizeof(animal));
    cats[i]->name = "Kitty";
}

//third array -- combination of first and second array
animal** all_animals = malloc(sizeof(animal*) * 8);
memcpy(all_animals, dogs, sizeof(animal*) * 5);
memcpy(all_animals + 5, cats, sizeof(animal*) * 3);
```

Would I need to free dogs, cats and all_animals? Or would freeing all_animals alone be sufficient?

Comment: yes you have to free `dogs` & `cats` after `memcpy`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: `memcpy(all_animals, cats, sizeof(animal*) * 3);` overwrite it.

Comment: OT: This `arr1[i]->name = "doggo";` mostly likely does not do what you expect.

Comment: OT: Also the 2nd call to `memcpy()` overwrites what the 1st call had copied. `memcpy()` does *not* automagically append (to an end it does not know).

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: To avoid memory leaks each call to `malloc()` & Friends need to be followed by exactly one call to `free()` (passing what a call to `malloc()`& Friends had returned).

Comment: [sample code](http://ideone.com/t7VfAz)

Comment: @Jens: "*Do you have a typedef for `animal`?*": Have a 2nd look: "*`animal** all_animals = malloc(sizeof(animal*) * 8);`*" ;)

Comment: @alk Ah yes, sorry. I rushed the quesion then changed things last minute.

Comment: @alk Fixed it :-)

Comment: Imagine if `memcpy` freed memory. How would you make a copy of something while keeping the original? How would you copy a stack variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Memcpy is just a memory copy, it does nothing smart under the hood - nor it should.

> memcpy is meant to be the fastest library routine for
>   memory-to-memory copy.

As such, you need to free all objects, dogs, cats, sqirrels etc.

Comment: This is for C and as far as I know std::memcpy isn't a thing in C, but thank you! That answers the question :)

Comment: Sorry, fixed. It applies to both C and C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy If it answers completely your question, please mark it. Otherwise do shout if something is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

The only functions (in Standard C) that free memory are `free()` and `realloc()` when it needs to move some memory block, or the new size is 0.

Comment: *when memory come from malloc